# Getting an exception during updating a table

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am updating a table in a database but it is continuously giving me an exception: NullReferenceException "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I have pasted the snippet down:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    double bal_due, a, b;
    a = double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString()); //this lines throws the exception
    b= double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
    bal_due = a - b;                        
    string var = string.Format(
        "update purchase_order set paid_today={0}, " + 
        "balance_due={1} where order_no={2}",
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value, bal_due, comboBox2.SelectedValue);
    obj.query(var);
}
```

Comment: Something is null. Which line throws the exception?

Comment: @Blorgbeard...check the code i have updated it

Comment: Cells[3].Value is probably null and you are calling ToString on it.

Comment: @DeveloperGuo...without using toString() it shows error and i do fill the Cell[3].Value is not empty.

Comment: I would put a breakpoint on that line, then in your watch or immediate window type each part of your dataGridView1.Row statement till it is completed so you can find out what is actually null

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to execute an update statement for the empty row at the bottom of your datagridview ... add this to your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].IsNewRow) continue;
    ...
```